# UIScrollView become very rough after adding new buttons

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

here iam trying to build an extended view using scrollView so my classes are :

```
ButtonsScroller.h
```

this is my component class , this class extends UIView and has uiscrollview

this is the main method in this class

```
-(void)buildUi {

buttonsCount=[buttonsArray count];

NSLog(@"Building Scroll With %d Buttons",buttonsCount);
NSLog(@", every row has %d Buttons",countOfButtonsInOneRow);
NSLog(@", every button Width is :  %d px",buttonWidth);
NSLog(@", every button height is :  %d px",buttonHeight);
NSLog(@", space Between Buttons In One Row   is :  %d px",marginsBetweenButtons);
NSLog(@", space Between 2 rows  is :  %d px",marginsBetweenRows);
NSLog(@"and number Of Rows To Be Shown :  %d row",rowsToShow);
int horizontalStart=horizontalStartFrom-buttonWidth;


int HORIZONTAL_CORDENATES=horizontalStart;

for(int bc=0;bc<buttonsCount;bc++){
    NSLog(@"buttons Counter : %d",bc);

    for(int g=0;g<countOfButtonsInOneRow;g++){
        if(bc==buttonsCount || bc>buttonsCount){
            break;
        }else {


            Expos *expo=[buttonsArray objectAtIndex:bc];

           //ExpoUIButton : My Custom UIView with buttons in it
            ExpoUIButton *btn=[[ExpoUIButton alloc]init];

            [btn.name setText:expo.userName];

            if(![expo.user_type isEqualToString:@"2"]){
                NSLog(@"[expo.user_type isEqualToString:1");
                [btn setType:0];
            }


            btn.frame=CGRectMake(HORIZONTAL_CORDENATES, VERTICAL_CORDENATES, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);                
            [scrollView addSubview:btn];
            bc=bc+1;
            HORIZONTAL_CORDENATES=HORIZONTAL_CORDENATES-(marginsBetweenButtons+buttonWidth);


        }
        NSLog(@"g : %d",g);
    }

    bc=bc-1;
    HORIZONTAL_CORDENATES=horizontalStart;
    VERTICAL_CORDENATES=VERTICAL_CORDENATES+(marginsBetweenRows+buttonHeight);
}

// ComputeRow Count 

int rowCount=buttonsCount;

// NSLog(@"rowCount%4  : %d",(rowCount%4 ));
while((rowCount%countOfButtonsInOneRow) !=0){
    NSLog(@"rowCount : %d",rowCount);
    rowCount=rowCount+1;
}

float rowCounts=(rowCount/countOfButtonsInOneRow);
NSLog(@"rowCounts : %f",rowCounts);


float viewHeight=rowsToShow*(buttonHeight)+(rowsToShow*marginsBetweenRows)+(buttonHeight/2);
NSLog(@"viewHeight : %f",viewHeight);

if(self.showLoadMore){
    if(loadMore==nil){
        loadMore=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [loadMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loadMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more-f"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [loadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(130, VERTICAL_CORDENATES+3, 68, 15)];

        [scrollView addSubview:loadMore];

    }else {
        [loadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(130, VERTICAL_CORDENATES+3, 68, 15)];
    }
      [scrollView  setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SC_WIDTH, VERTICAL_CORDENATES+25)];
}else {
    [scrollView  setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SC_WIDTH, VERTICAL_CORDENATES)];
} 
}
```

in my mainView Controller i start a connection and when the connection done this method invoked

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - YttpConnectionDelegate
-(void) YConnectionDoneWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)items {
    NSLog(@"items : %d",[items count]);
    if([items count]>0  ){
        exposArray =items;
        [productsList hideLoadingView];
        [productsList setButtonsArray:exposArray];
        [productsList buildUi  ];
        SEL selector = @selector(loadDataFromInternet);
        [productsList loadMoreBtnSelector:selector target:self];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    } else {
        [productsList hideLoadingMoreButton];
    }
}
```

when i open my view and the frist set of buttons loaded the view is still ok , but
the problem arise when the second set of buttons added , the uiscrollview become rough and all the buttons (the old ones , and the new )are not clickable

also , if i go back to my firstVC view and then go to the scrollviewVC screen after loading the first set of buttons , all the buttons are still not clickable
so what is the problem ?!

Edit :

as i think this is a refresh issue ?!

Comment: do you remove the old buttons when creating the new set of buttons? also are you using -arc?

Comment: no i don't remove the old case i need them , i use arc

Comment: I'd say you've overridden `drawRect` and done it not effectively. Try to replace custom buttons with the standard

Comment: i tried to use standers buttons but  still have the same problem , about drawRect when and where i have to override it , and what i have to write in ?!

Comment: i found the problem , i was sending the event of load more in a wrong way , i created a method in ButtonsScroller.h to br used in the mainVC to set the action of loadMore Button , i was passing a selector from mainVc to ButtonsScroller and that was a wrong way -because : as i think it was a buffer overflow issue - but i changed it and used delegates so it's working great now , thanks alot